# Restart canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html, loops, canvas

There's a HTML5 game tutorial on w3schools [link](http://www.w3schools.com/games/tryit.asp?filename=trygame_obstacles_random)

I'm trying to add a button below the canvas to restart the game:

```
<button onmouseup="startGame()">Restart</button>
```

and add a clear function to for loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < myObstacles.length; i += 1) {
    if (myGamePiece.crashWith(myObstacles[i])) {
        myGameArea.stop();
        myGameArea.clear();
        return;
    } 
}
```

so it clears the canvas.

The problem is the function startGame() don't want to start the game again.
Where is the problem?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I did:

```
<button onmousedown="restart()">Restart</button>
```

And then I defined a new function called `restart`:

```
function restart() {
    myGameArea.stop();
    myGameArea.clear();
    startGame();
}
```

It should restart now, but the obstacles from the previous game(s) still remain. To fix this, you need to clear the `myObstacles` array before restarting the game. This is how I did it:

```
function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myObstacles = []; // it is very important to do this before starting the game
    myGameArea.start();
}
```

Working jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/11wrorox/